# Authentication using AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I make a simple program to simulate authentication using AJAX and PHP. The following is my code. It will redirect to "/?" but nothing happened. I tried to use `checkLogin(); return false;` in `onclick` event but it didn't work.

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Username <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
        <input id="usernamelogin" type="text" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
        <input id="passwordlogin" type="text" value="" />
    </p>                
    <p>
        <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="checkLogin()" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**validation.js**

```
function checkLogin(){
    var u = document.getElementById("usernamelogin").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("passwordlogin").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onReadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == u){
                alert(':)');
            }
            else{
                alert(':(');
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "login.php?u=" + u + "&p=" + p, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    $u = $_GET['u'];
    $p = $_GET['p'];

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'db';

    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if(!$con) die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db, $con);
    $query = "select username from login where username = '" . $u . "' and password = '" . $p . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['username'];
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why not using `/login.php` to be sure it will perform request to the same URL independent from the current URL. Also could you check if any  XHR requests are performed using the Developer tools of Chrome or Firebug for Firefox?

Comment: if you like , i have suggestions 
1) mysql_* are depricated
2)this authentication method is very weak!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you didn't sanitize your db inputs which is very dangerous. Certainly not safe for production.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev I tried `/login.php` and it didn't work. I'm checking the XHR requests.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev: I checked it using the Developer Tools in Chrome and I saw a request and its response like I want. But it didn't trigger the alert. Why is that?

Comment: @shankshera Check the status of the request. If it's not 200 it will not trigger an alert according to your code. Also you could try logging the `xmlhttp` object in your `onReadystatechange` event handler to see the `readyState` property.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev Thanks for your help, its status is 200. Turns out it must be `onreadystatechange` not `onReadystatechange`. Unbelievable. I use auto complete feature in Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change the following code

```
xmlhttp.onReadystatechange
```

to

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

and it works. And also use `onclick="checkLogin(); return false;"` in input `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the onclick event from the input type="submit" and add it to the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkLogin()">
```

To let this work, you have to add

```
return false
```

to your javascript function, right before you close the function

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work. The result I get is same as when I put `onclick='checkLogin()'; return false;` in input type="submit".